SymPy having trouble plotting Bessel functions - cannot recognize ```besselj``` within its own namespace
It seems like SymPy is having some issues plotting a Bessel function. This is the working example:
import sympy as sp

x = sp.symbols('x')

sp.plot(sp.besselj(4,x), (x,1,2))

When I try running the block above, I get the following stack trace:
File "/Users/..../test_bessel.py", line 5, in <module>
    sp.plot(sp.besselj(4,x), (x,1,2))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py", line 419, in plot
    plots.show()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/plotting/backends/textbackend/text.py", line 21, in show
    textplot(ser.expr, ser.start, ser.end)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/plotting/textplot.py", line 167, in textplot
    for line in textplot_str(expr, a, b, W, H):
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sympy/plotting/textplot.py", line 67, in textplot_str
    y.append(f(val))
             ^^^^^^
  File "<lambdifygenerated-1>", line 2, in _lambdifygenerated
NameError: name 'besselj' is not defined

I don't quite understand how besselj is not defined, as I imported it with the sympy namespace. Any pointers here are greatly appreciated!

The code as shown works fine for me. What version of SymPy are you using?

I'm using version 1.13.2

Looking at the traceback, I would guess you don't have matplotlib installed in your environment.

@Davide_sd , you are completely correct. I've installed matplotlib into the environment and now the figure is correctly generated. Thank you!
